# JavaScript insert button before link, not after

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following example of code where I insert a button after the page is loaded, and I would like for that button to go inside of that div, but after that link is it posible ([link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7jy8/))?

#### HTML

```
<div class="someclass" id="someid">
    <a href="#" class="">Text Here</a>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
(function(root) {
    function bindUIActions() {
        menuElements();
    }
    function menuElements() {
        var menuElements = document.getElementById("someid");
        menuElements.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin','<button type="menu-button" id="responsiveToggle" class="menu-button" aria-hidden="true"><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-reorder"></i>Menu</button>');
    }
    root.NavigationWidget = {
        init: function() {
            bindUIActions();
        }
    };

})(this);
NavigationWidget.init();
```

Comment: +1 - You just don't see `insertAdjacentHTML` enough anymore, wonder why ?

Comment: Honestly... I have never seen it before now, NICE!!!

Comment: @PhillipWills - it was nice in 1996 when it was more commonly used, I don't think anyone uses this much anymore, as the preferred way is to use the append and prepend methods for elements.

Comment: what can i say, i'm an old guy :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a lot of code, but the more proper way to do it would be:

```
var menuElements = document.getElementById("someid"),
    button       = document.createElement('button'),
    i            = document.createElement('i'),
    txt          = document.createTextNode('Menu');

button.type      = 'button';
button.id        = 'responsiveToggle';
button.className = 'menu-button';

i.className      = 'icon-reorder';

button.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
i.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');

button.appendChild(i);
button.appendChild(txt);
menuElements.appendChild(button);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7jy8/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use 'beforeend'

```
menuElements.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<button type="menu-button" id="responsiveToggle" class="menu-button" aria-hidden="true"><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-reorder"></i>Menu</button>');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: already checked out the mdn :-) and beforeend wouldn't be a solution to my problem :D